# Having trouble when try to trigger text editor from ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell. From some video, I see people can trigger text editor from ghci. It says if you don't set up the default text editor, it will hint you to use `set editor` command. But in my case, when I input

```
edit
```

It gives me an error saying

```
error: Variable not in scope: edit
```

How can I solve it? I'm using Haskell stack 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ghci command all begin with `:`. Try `:edit` instead.

- https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:edit

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `:edit`, you can run arbitrary shell commands with `:!`, so if your editor were, for example, `vim`, you might open a file with it using `:!vim foo.hs`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `:edit`. All GHCi commands such as `:load` and `:set` are prefixed with a colon `:`.